# How to decode windowsCP1252 encoded string Swift

Tags: swift, nsstringencoding, cp1252

From a web service my application receiving a JSON response. In which one field is a `windowsCP1252` encoded string.

I am trying to decode it with following code,

```
let input =  "à´¸àµ—à´ªàµ¼à´£à´¿à´•"//a string from server response
let data = input.data(using: .windowsCP1252, allowLossyConversion: true)!
print("data \(data.description)")

let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

print("output \(output ?? "failed")")
```

But, it is failing to convert. thus printing failed.

Same server response is converted in android with following kotlin code.

```
val input = "à´¸àµ—à´ªàµ¼à´£à´¿à´•"
val op = String(input.toByteArray(charset("Cp1252")), charset("UTF-8"))
println("converted string -----  " + op )
```

This kotlin code is decoding the string correctly and printing
`converted string -----  സൗപർണിക`

What is wrong with swift implementation?
How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that 1251 is not the same as 1252.

```
let s = "à´¸àµ—à´ªàµ¼à´£à´¿à´•"
let d = s.data(using: .windowsCP1252)
let s2 = String(data: d!, encoding: .utf8) // "സൗപർണിക"
```

Comment: Actually it was 1252, I tried both 1252 and 1251. Example copied from 1251 try(updated my question). 
1252 is working for small strings. but not for lengthy strings